# VHDL keypad code issues

Tags: vhdl, keypad

I have a 4x3 keypad, i wrote this FSM for interfacing it with my Nexys2 board, trouble I am having here is

1. When I run the code, the LEDs glow without any key pressed, it shows random combinations automatically
2. When I press a key it shows that particular combination then goes on to the next condition of ROW without any key pressed. And sometimes it does not even respond if i press a key.

What is happening? What is wrong with this code? I am clueless. Can someone point out the mistakes and suggest some solution? Here is my code

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity keypad_3x4 is
     Port ( CLK     : in  STD_LOGIC;
              RESET     : in  STD_LOGIC;
              ROW   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              COL   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
              LED       : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0)
              );
end keypad_3x4;


architecture Behavioral of keypad_3x4 is
architecture Behavioral of keypad_3x4 is


 TYPE STATE_TYPE is
    (   RESET_ST,
        S1,
        S2,
        S3,
        S4,
        S5,
        S6
    );

signal  state:  STATE_TYPE;
begin

 process (CLK, RESET)
 begin

    if  (RESET = '1') then
        state       <= RESET_ST;    
    elsif   (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then

    case (state) is 

    WHEN RESET_ST       =>
            LED             <= (others => '0');
            COL         <= (others => '0');
            state           <= S1;

    WHEN S1         =>
        COL             <= "001";       --C1 selected
        LED             <= (others => '0');
        state           <= S2;

    WHEN S2         =>
        if  ROW         <= "0001" then
                led         <= "0001";  --1     
        elsif ROW       <= "0010" then
                led         <= "0100";  --4     
        elsif ROW       <= "0100" then
                led         <= "0111";  --7     
        elsif ROW       <= "1000" then
                led         <= "1111";  --*     
        else
                LED         <= (others => '0');
                state       <= S3;
        end if;

    WHEN S3         =>
        COL             <= "010";       --C2 selected
        LED         <= (others => '0');
        state           <= S4;

    WHEN S4     =>
        if  ROW <= "0001" then
                led <= "0010";  --2 
        elsif ROW <= "0010" then
                led <= "0101";  --5     
        elsif ROW <= "0100" then
                led <= "1000";  --8
        elsif ROW <= "1000" then
                led <= "0000";  --0
        else
                LED         <= (others => '0');
                state       <= S5;
        end if;

    WHEN S5     =>
        COL             <= "100";       --C3 selected
        LED             <= (others => '0');
        state           <= S6;

    WHEN S6     =>
        if  ROW <= "0001" then
                led <= "0011";  --3
        elsif ROW <= "0010" then
                led <= "0110";  --6
        elsif ROW <= "0100" then
                led <= "1001"; --9
        elsif ROW <= "1000" then
                led <= "1111";  --#
        else
                LED         <= (others => '0');
                state       <= RESET_ST;
        end if;

    WHEN others =>
                state       <= RESET_ST;    
    END case;
END if;
END process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Are these keys debounced?

Comment: No they are not because i don't think there is a need, I only want display. the code is scanning continuously and the LEDs are off in the else statement.

Comment: I agree with David, you should probably debounce these.  The state machine might see a single key press with some glitches on it and think that it was multiple key presses.  Additionally, your state machine starts up in RESET_ST, but it immediately goes to S1, then S2, etc.  You don't actually wait for a key to be pressed to get out of RESET_ST.  Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: Additionally, you need to look at Row and Col together to know which key is being pressed.  Think about it.  3 Is selected when Row = 1 and Col = 3.  Your state machine does not keep track of this.

Comment: clock rate, pull downs on row inputs (pull ups on row inputs if device buffers are inverting)?  The idea here is whether or not the row inputs are 'pumped' to some input voltage level pushing you through others choice until only one row valid.