# Use a 4x4 Keypad on Basys3 FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado, keypad

I want to make a simple VHDL program using Vivado to register the input from a 4x4 keypad ([this model](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1463&bih=756&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=9kCOXNyeHYqwgwfb07DIBw&q=4x4+keypad&oq=4x4+keypad&gs_l=img.3..0j0i7i30l9.3371993.3372283..3372414...0.0..0.99.175.2......1....1..gws-wiz-img.90OcGSgn19M#imgrc=sybsc6XEcFyLzM:)) and display that value on the 7-segment display that this board has.

To do so, by reading the [Basys3 manual](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/basys3:basys3_rm.pdf), my guess is that I have to connect the row and column pins to one of the Pmod ports (I want to use the JB Pmod port) the following way:

> A14 to Row1,  A16 to Row2,  B15 to Row3,  B16 to Row4
>
> A15 to Col1,   A17 to Col2,  C15 to Col3,  C16 to Col4

and the entity to use has to be similar to this

```
entity Keypad is
    Port (
        clk        : in  std_logic; 
        reset      : in  std_logic;
        row_vector : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        col_vector : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        code       : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end Keypad;
```

so I can use row_vector[0], row_vector[1], row_vector[2] and row_vector[3] as Row1, Row2, Row3 and Row4 respectively, and the same with the columns.

The code variable will take its value according to the following table

[image]

My question is. How do I start to implement this problem? According to some other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822545/vhdl-keypad-code-issues), `col_vector` is an output and I do not understand why. I want to approach this project using the tutorial of [this webpage](http://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-set-up-a-keypad-on-an-arduino/).

I know how to implement a debouncer for the keys and a State Machine to go through the steps that the linked page has, but my problem is that I do not undestand how to read the input from the keypad since all the projects I've made were reading the buttons that comes with the board, and those were simpler.

Comment: Just like reading the buttons you talked about. The only difference is that you have 4 inputs signals which you read at the same time, instead of one.

Comment: @Oldfart That means that the keypad buttons are active high? I'm confused since according to the linked webpage initially the column vector would be "1111" and the row vector "0000"

Comment: Reading and active high (or low) are unrelated. You read and then you check if it is "active".  `if row_vector[i]= the_active_status_level then -- we have a key press `. Side note: in hardware we use the term 'asserted'. *Asserted* means the signals is active which can be active high or active low. A good programmer makes this obvious using the right signal name. e.g. `reset_n -- is an active low reset`.